# Windows 8 App - Default pin to Start Menu after installation

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I have a windows 8 app, I want once the user downloads it, it pins to the start menu. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a setting that the user can turn on or off (to auto add apps there). They may have updated this out of there, but in both cases. The answer is no you can't do that

Comment: but most current apps still have this functionality.